# Can't access form control programatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a `Service` class (in `Service.cs`) that does some logic that I want to separate from the `Form.cs` code.

It also modifies some of the form's components and instead of trying to pass all the controls when calling methods from `Service`, I tried keeping the `Form` data in a static variable (`Globals.form` - see in the method presented below).

I've been encountering a problem in one of my `Service` methods:

```
public static void UpdateFileInfo()
{
    TreeView Filelist = (TreeView)Globals.form.Controls["Filelist"];
    Filelist.Nodes[0].Text = "Name: " + fi.Name;
    
    *** some more code here ***
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access a form control with `Globals.form.Controls["Filelist"]`.

Whenever this method gets called, I get a:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I debugged my code, and saw that `Filelist` actually stores nothing, and it should have stored a `TreeView` component, as my form has a `TreeView` control called `Filelist`. I didn't encounter this before (my TreeView was initially named `treeView1`, but as soon as I renamed the control into `Filelist`, this seems to happen). I did rename it only from the form's designer. Didn't look in other areas.

Could this be a problem of Visual Studio? I also followed the answer provided on the [Microsoft Learn Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/126187/microsoft-visual-studio-object-reference-not-set-t.html), but just deleting these folders didn't seem to work, because I'm receiving the same Exception.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: A service shouldn't have any gui components.  There shouldn't be anything in `UpdateFileInfo` that needs a gui control.

Comment: @LarsTech That sounds pretty solid to me. But what if I'm talking about some `ThemeService`, that changes component font/colors, based on user input? Should I just return a list of strings, containing those colors and manage the controls in my `Form.cs`?

Comment: Don't know enough about your project, but it sounds like maybe using a json file would work. So, yes, strings.